# Safari Browser (iPhone Simulator): How to see/monitor all events being triggered?

Tags: macos, debugging, safari, ios-simulator, dom-events

I'm using the iPhone Simulator in Safari OSX to debug my JavaScript. I'm using the Console, however, as there is a number of event handlers on the page (plus I'd like to see if the browser also fires any additional events, e.g. :hover on touch) it would very useful to see ANY/ALL events being fired in real-time. I found an article about how to do it in Firefox/FireBug.. anything like this for Safari/iPhone Simulator?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 3):

`monitorEvents` also works in Safari (iOS 11).

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/quickly-monitor-events-from-the-console-panel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does not seem to work while using web Inspector on IOS Safari