# slide on iphone safari causes toggle to fire bug

Tags: jquery, iphone, debugging, safari, slide

On http://inigo.nu (temporary project)

I use clicking a div to toggle display a menu ul using

html:

`<div id="toggle-menu" class="hover">menu</div>`

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery('#toggle-menu').on('click', function() {
        jQuery('nav ul').toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Only on **iPhone safari** a strange bug occurs.

Sliding after opening the menu with a click makes the just opened menu dissappear again.
What causes this strange behavior and how can I fix it?

Sadly this post: [Safari Browser (iPhone Simulator): How to see/monitor all events being triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713106/safari-browser-iphone-simulator-how-to-see-monitor-all-events-being-triggered) was never answered. Cause I like to see the triggered events.

I console.log ed the slide event but that didn't clear things up for my.

So my side question would be **how to best debug** such an issue.

I installed developer on Safari desktop and have no js errors. 
On the slide display is set inline to none like it would onclick.
There are no padding or overlay issues going on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found your question when I was working on solving the same issue for a client of mine. The client has a mobile navigation which is revealed when a "toggle icon" is clicked. Originally the script used .toggle()....which yes is a deprecated function as of jQuery 1.9 (client is using 1.7.2 and can't switch it), but I replicate the exact problem you described using both toggle/slideToggle.

I'll explain my solution in detail and label the sections you may want to skip.

### Script I Used

The script that I was editing to fix this problem is for a navigation. It does a "toggle" event to display the nav area and checks if the browser is at a mobile width (if not, then it hides all of the mobile elements).

### Attempted Solutions/Steps Taken

I initially tried to switch from toggle() to slideToggle(), just to see what would happen. To no surprise, the issue was the same.

I then switched to a more optimal approach by toggling a display class on the relevant elements. This appeared to work fine, but it ultimately led to the same problem: the moment you scroll on the iPad the class reverted itself.

### The Solution

This to me was interesting, because my script was a click event, yet it was firing on scroll.

As I noted above, there was a resize function that was supposed to rehide stuff when the browser got above the mobile breakpoint. The original resize function was really sub-optimal IMO, so I opted to update it it just on a hunch.

**Old**

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if( $(window).width > 700 ) {
        $(".visible").removeClass("visible");
    }
});
```

**New**

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ( $(window).matchMedia('(min-width: 788px)').matches ) {
        $(".visible").removeClass("visible");
    }
});
```

Using matchMedia turned out to be exactly what I needed all along. I ultimately kept the class toggles though :).

But again, what in god's name would cause a resize to trigger on scroll? According to the jQuery team, this is a bug with Safari/iOS associated with .resize(). Note: it's not a jQuery bug, the issue just relates to that event.

Source: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14119

Note that the responder indicates the issue is resolved when he uses a POJO event listener vs the jQuery equivalent. The example they provide doesn't actually deal with matchMedia, however I think I can extrapolate what's happening:

#### My Theory

I believe that Safari is triggering jQuery's .resize() event on scroll incorrectly, which is causing the script to fire when it shouldn't. I believe my issue was solved by match media because even if the script re-fires, it won't do anything since the matchMedia statement evaluates to false, vs looking at the window width via $(window).width().

Either way I hope this helps you or someone else somehow.